# Insect identification (Brazil, orthoptera?)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This insect appeared in my indoor yard, in southeastern Brazil. The body is roughly 2cm in length and it makes very distinct beeping sounds, in a pattern that sounds almost like morse code, unlike the crickets I've seen around here. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: According to the author of [this blog](http://www.insetologia.com.br/2017/01/possivel-grilo-endecous-em-minas-gerais.html), this appears to be an Endecous Phalangopsinae/Luzarinae, but they don't rest with the wings like that. I'll try to capture it the next time. http://www.ib.usp.br/~silvionihei/2014%20Souza-Dias%20Endecous%20apterus.pdf https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230188107_New_Brazilian_species_of_Endecous_Saussure_1878_Phallic_sclerites_calling_song_and_tegmen_morphometry_Orthoptera_Grylloidea_Phalangopsinae

Comment: The species in the question's picture could very well be related, but the papers you reference describe different colored/sized species that, more importantly, live in different habitats (i.e., caves). Unless your yard is near a cave or major source of bat guano, I'd say you'll have to keep hoping someone finds a more accurate answer.

Comment: @theforestecologist The identification seems to be fair, see my answer appended. Disclaimer: I am no specialist myself but I really trust the web of contacts at the blog <Insetologia>

Comment: By far the best online forum and resource for the identification of Brazilian arthropods is the website below (in Portuguese): http://www.insetologia.com.br It adds to the discussion offered by @theforestecologist in this thread, given the identification of similar specimens at: http://www.insetologia.com.br/2017/12/provavel-grilo-endecous-em-sao-paulo.html http://www.insetologia.com.br/2017/01/possivel-grilo-endecous-em-minas-gerais.html
[This one looks like the OP here?] This is one interesting occurrence.

Comment: Its a cricket with bad moulted wings. (Probably)